# Sending a request to an URL

Tags: c#

I'm trying to send a request to my phone at my desk. I can do it in my browser simply by entering in the following:

```
http://ip.address/cgi-bin/api-make_call?phonenumber="number"&account="account"&password="password"
```

This works fine and makes an outbound call to the "number"

I've tried this using:

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://ip.address/cgi-bin/api-make_call?phonenumber=phonenumber");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(account, password);
```

I've used HTTPWebResponse and get something like:

```
{"response":"error", "body": ""}
```

But I'm unsure what to make of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove

```
  request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(account, password);
```

the code above it for other use.

You have to change your first line like this

```
string number = "666666666";
string account = "youraccount";
string password = "password"; 
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://ip.address/cgi-bin/api-make_call?phonenumber=" + number + "&account=" +account+"&password="+ password);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the other query string arguments in the string. They also may need to be in quotes, though I'm not certain.

Here's a function that will get it for you if you pass in the appropriate values:

```
public static string GetCallUrl(string phone, string account, string password)
{
    var baseUrl = "http://ip.address/cgi-bin/api-make_call";

    var queryString = string.Format(
        "?phonenumber=\"{0}\"&account=\"{1}\"&password=\"{2}\"",
        phone, account, password);

    return string.Concat(baseUrl, queryString);
}
```

Usage:

```
var phone = "2065551212";
var account = "12345";
var password = "letmein";

WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(GetCallUrl(phone, account, password));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try with the correct url in a navigator

http://SERVER_IP/cgi-bin/api-make_call?phonenumber=100&account=0&user=admin&password=admin

and your code should be:

```
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://SERVER_IP/cgi-bin/api-make_call?phonenumber=100&account=0&user=admin&password=admin")
```

account is for line key, not for logging.

I hope, it works for you.

Regards